# What addresses does authoritative DNS server keep?

Tags: networking, dns

[image]

[image]

Why does yahoo's authoritative DNS server keeps stackoverflow's ip? Or is it my local DNS server that has stackoverflow's ip in its cache? (as described here - the firsr dns (1/2) has the ip in its cache so it doesn't eve bother to contact the other DNS servers?) How can I "force" my pc to ask ns3.yahoo.com for specific ip without getting answer from any cache? thanks!

Comment: sorry for the links, I cant post images as my reputation is below 10.

Comment: I just tried that. I did not get any response from the server.

Comment: I get "query refused"; what version of Windows is this?

Comment: To be honest you already did use the correct syntax. `nslookup domain ns_server` will ask ns_server for specified domain. It bypasses your DNS server and caches. Yahoo DNS server must have had the stackoverflow ip cached and allowed the query. I do not see any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you got that answer, I get this, at least on Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\dude> nslookup stackoverflow.com ns3.yahoo.com
Server:  ns3.yahoo.com
Address:  203.84.221.53

*** ns3.yahoo.com can't find stackoverflow.com: Query refused
C:\Users\dude>
```

Try running nslookup interactively turning on the debug option to see what it's really asking for... here I see I'm just REFUSED for every variation using the local search list and IPv4 & IPv6 addresses.  *I suspect you either have an entry for "stackoverflow.com" in your local host table, or you're hitting a "special" mirror of ns3.yahoo.com that is allowing recursive queries for your source address space.*

```
C:\Users\dude> nslookup - ns3.yahoo.com
Default Server:  ns3.yahoo.com
Address:  203.84.221.53

> set debug
> stackoverflow.com
Server:  ns3.yahoo.com
Address:  203.84.221.53

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = REFUSED
        header flags:  response, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        stackoverflow.com.localdomain.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = REFUSED
        header flags:  response, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        stackoverflow.com.localdomain.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = REFUSED
        header flags:  response, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        stackoverflow.com, type = A, class = IN

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = REFUSED
        header flags:  response, want recursion
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        stackoverflow.com, type = AAAA, class = IN

------------
*** ns3.yahoo.com can't find stackoverflow.com: Query refused
>
```

Comment: I got the same output as u when i changed network :) probably my local DNS has stackoverflow's ip in its cache... thanks!